# Magento 2 Unable to update customer data during passing to customer login observer

Tags: magento2, database, event-observer, customer-login

In magento 2 I am trying to update `session_cutoff` column in table `customer_entity` during login

Below is my code which I add in observer using event `customer_login`

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->_customerSession->setGTMSuccessfulLogin($this->helper->successfulLoginPushData());

        $customer_data = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $gtrustCustNo = $customer_data->getData('gtrust_custno');

        $param = array('custNo' => $gtrustCustNo);
        $result = $this->_gtrustApiHelper->getUserBenefit(($param));
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer = $customer->setWebsiteId(1);
        // set sessionCutOff to null
        $customer = $customer->setSessionCutOff(NULL);
        $customer = $customer->loadByEmail($customer_data->getEmail());
        $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();       
        if (isset($result['resultData']['result']['usableSaveamt'])){
            $saveamt = $result['resultData']['result']['usableSaveamt'];
            $this->_customerSession->setCustomerPoint($saveamt);
            $customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_point', $saveamt);
        }
        if (isset($result['resultData']['result']['usePbDeposit'])){
            $deposit = $result['resultData']['result']['usePbDeposit'];
            $customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_deposit', $deposit);
        }
        if (isset($result['resultData']['result']['usableCouponCnt'])){
            $coupon = $result['resultData']['result']['usableCouponCnt'];
            $this->_customerSession->setCouponDownloaded($coupon);
            $customerData->setCustomAttribute('coupon_downloaded', $coupon);
        }        
        $customer->updateData($customerData);
        $customer->save();        
    }
```

As you can see I already added the `$customer->setSessionCutOff(NULL);` to set the customer `session_cutoff` to null but apparently when I try login the value doesnt change

I already `var_dump` to confirm whether the observer is being read or not, and able to see clearly that the soure code is being read and passed through during login

`$customer->setWebsiteId(1)` also didn't work I check, I already dicompile, upgrade and cache clean but nothing works

Please help check and advice on what is causing this issue

Comment: I think the method of ‘session_cutoff’ should be ‘ $customer->setSessionCutoff(NULL);’

Comment: @AmiyoGhosh when I try to use $customer->setSessionCutoff(NULL); it return error "Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::setSessionCutoff()"

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you're trying to achieve with the customer factory and calling `loadByEmail`? Do you not already have the customer entity you want from the observer event? Seems you are assigning data to a new customer entity created by the customer factory, then reloading it using the email from the customer entity attached to the observer event?

Would something like this be better?

```php
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$gtrustCustNo = $customer->getData('gtrust_custno');
$param = array('custNo' => $gtrustCustNo);
$result = $this->_gtrustApiHelper->getUserBenefit(($param));

$customer->setWebsiteId(1);
$customer->setSessionCutOff(null);
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
```

I'd also advise you be more defensive with the rest of your logic, like asserting `$gtrustCustNo` contains the values you'd expect etc.

Comment: Thank you, the update is working now, but when I try use $customer->setSessionCutOff(null); I got error "Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::setSessionCutOff()"

Comment: Can you try $customer->setData('session_cutoff', null) instead of $customer->setSessionCutOff(null)?